When I click on the login text, I am not directed to the "/login" page
When you click on "Login" on the home page, a login window opens in the middle of the screen, but there is no redirection to /login. Why?
I want the login window to open and be directed to /login. If the login is correct, I will redirect to another page, if it is incorrect, I will send an error message.
<li>
  <ion-icon name="person-outline" class="nav-icon"></ion-icon>
  <a class="main-nav-link show-modal" href="/login">Giriş</a>
</li>

<div class="giris gizle">
  <button class="giris-kapat">&times;</button>
  <h1 class="giris-name">Giriş</h1>
  <div>
    <form action="/login" method="POST">
      <ul class="giris-list">
        <li class="giris-item">
          <p class="giris-text">Kullanıcı Adı:</p>
          <input type="text" name="username" />
        </li>
        <li class="giris-item">
          <p class="giris-text">Şifre:</p>
          <input type="password" name="password" />
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="submit" class="giris-btn">Giriş</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

router.get("/login", async (req, res) => {});

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
const { username, password } = req.body; // Formdan gelen veriyi al

try {
  const request = new sql.Request();
  const result = await request
    .input("username", sql.VarChar, username) // Kullanıcı adını parametre olarak ver
    .input("password", sql.VarChar, password) // Şifreyi parametre olarak ver
    .query("SELECT * FROM Kullanicilar WHERE kullaniciAdi = @username AND kullaniciSifre = @password"); // Sorgu

  if (result.recordset.length > 0) {
    console.log("giriş başarılı");
    res.render("user-page");
  } else {
    console.log("Geçersiz kullanıcı adı veya şifre");
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Giriş işlemi sırasında hata oluştu:", err);
  res.status(500).send("Giriş sırasında bir hata oluştu.");
}


The error might be in the href tag. If you simply write '/login' it means a folder but if you write '/login.(extension name)' then it might work.

it's a call to backend (express), it's not a call to local files
